# Hiding an inline image in css and displaying another one while the screen is smaller

Tags: html, image, css

My issue is that when I have the page full screen I need it to display the header image and navigation bar. But when it is shrunk for mobile use I need it to display a different heading. The problem is that I can either get both images to display, which looks weird. Or I can get neither to display. I tried assigning and id to call within the css but no luck. With the posted code it displays neither but if I take out the header img display none, they both show up. First post here so I am sorry if there is any confusion **here is my html**

```
  <header>

     <nav class="horizontal">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tee Times</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Restaurant</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

     <img src="willet.png" alt="Willet Creek" />

  </header>
```

**and here is my css**

```
header nav, header img,  #main, aside, footer {
    display: none;
}

/*mobile styles */

html {
        background-color: rgb(107,  140, 80);
}

/*header styles */
header {
    background: rgb(151, 201, 151) url(willet.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    -o-background-image-size: contain;
    -moz-background-image-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-image-size: contain;
    background-image-size: contain;
    background-image-width: 100%;
    background-image-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Media Rule. Please see 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Example

```
header{
    background: url('image.jpg')
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    header{
        background: url('image-2.jpg')
    }
}
```

Comment: I used a media rule later on for landscape orientation.@media screen and (orientation: landscape){

nav#holes li {
 width: 30%; 
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
}


} do i need to add another one for just the image?

Comment: just added an example. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You needs to handle it using media query. Your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vLp6tv5e/ Remember you need to resize the page to see it working.

HTML:

```
<header>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header
{
    height:100px;
    background-image:url('big-image.jpg');
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    header 
    {
        background-image: url('small-image.jpg');
    }
}
```